# Is it possible to add custom buttons to the top of the Sitecore Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, customization, page-editor

I am trying to customize the Sitecore Page Editor at a website. Their home page displays a news viewer sublayout on it. The news items are not entered directrly below the home page but in an entirely different place in the Sitecore Content Tree.

This means that the normal insert option of the Page Editor only displays templates valid on the level below the home item. As that doesn't include news items the news item template is not mentioned. That's as expected.

What I am looking for is a way -preferably by a very obvious option on the top of the Page Editor- to allow the user to insert a new news item. The system should place it correctly in the Content Tree.

Any idea's on what mechanism I should be looking into? I looked into Edit frames and that's still an option but I would prefer to add buttons to the top of the Page Editor.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I think that the Edit Frame is the least confusing option for the end user.
Another option could be changing the Ribbon and adding some buttons there.
You can find the Ribbon in the core database: /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit

Also you can output some code only in the WebEdit: Sitecore.Context.PageMode will help you identify in which mode you are.

Comment: I think I am going to add an edit frame on the top of the page and add some options to it. Thanks, Alex.